# Private APNS server?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to use notifications with my iPhone/iPad application but for demo purpose, the application is running in a private network (no connection with apple APNS server).
Is there a java library/server that i can install and use in my private network to emulate APNS server ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use another push notifications server. All notifications must be sent to Apple servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are application dependent possibilities to use private push notification servers. One of them is iSip VOIP client from Vnet-corp. Vnet-corp makes a private push server available for their iSip app as VMware and VirtualBox image: http://www.vnet-corp.com/UserSGuideDownload.htm